# What type of ActionResult should I return from an MVC Action where I want javascript to either redirect or update a div?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Let me first outline my objective from a user's perspective and then the code I have to achieve that goal where its falling short.

I'd like the user to be able to click a button, which brings up a jQuery modal style dialog with a few fields on it and a submit + cancel button. When they successfully commit the record I'd like to have the user redirected to /Records/CustomList/ -- but if there is an error, I'd like the content of the div that is modal to be updated to show the ModelState errors I added and returned.

My question is, since I want to tell my clientside javascript what it should do based on the result of the action, what type should I return from my ActionResult method? I'm thinking a JSON object with two fields, Type and Data so I can write JS like this

```
if(ret.Type == 1) {
    window.location(ret.Data);
}
else {
    ('#modalDiv').html(ret.Data);
}
```

Is that a good approach? Is different option I should check out first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds about right. However the code will probably get a little bit more readable if you return a JSON object that looks more like this:

```
{
    type : 1,
    href : 'uri-to-redirect-to',
    errormessages : ['error1','error2']
}
```

And your javascript can look like this

```
if(ret.type === 1){
    window.location(ret.href);
}else{
    //add error messages to modalDiv
}
```

Also, don't use the == operator. `if(ret.type == true)` will evaluate to the same as `if(ret.type == 1)`. This might not matter in this case, but for future reference, stay away from the == operator unless you're absolutely positive you want this kind of functionality.

Comment: I actually want to pass back the entire PartialView in the 'data' field, not just the error messages. I like the idea of separating the html vs the url into to fields though.